# How can you georefernce rasters on the fly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

How can you georefernce rasters on the fly in QGIS.

In ArcGIS Pro when I start georeferencing and adding control points the raster will start to shift as I’m plotting the control points. So I can see right away if the gcp are working.

However, in QGIS there doesn’t seem to be an option to do this. You have to open a separate window called “georeferencer” and place the points between the 2 windows (map canvas and georeferencer). Then you have to run the translate to see the results.

Since we work with large 2-10 gb orthos with 3-5cm resolution. This can take up to 30 mins to process. Then we notice that it didn’t georefernce correctly and have to do it again. This sometimes can waste hours of our time.

Since we are using macs we don’t have the luxury of ArcGIS Pro :(.

Is there any solutions out there ?

Comment: ArcGIS Pro will run on Mac with M1 or M2 Chips (There is also Parallels or VM options to run windows on a Mac) https://www.apple.com/us/shop/buy-mac/macbook-air/with-m2-chip

Comment: How do you know it will run on M1 chips ?

Comment: If you only need a 2 point georeferencing tool (rotate, shift, scale) you can try the freehand georeference plugin: http://gvellut.github.io/FreehandRasterGeoreferencer/

Comment: @AdamGIS ArcGIS MacBook iPad https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TznwDi_jhrA